# An array of zeros in a for loop in MATLAb

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've an array of zeros which is defined like this:

```
a=zeros(1,N)
```

Now,in a for loop,i need to have jth element of this array to be 1,and n-1 other elemnts to be zero,how should i do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibilty:

```
for jj = 1:N
    a = [zeros(1,jj-1) 1 zeros(1,N-jj)];
    %// do stuff
end
```

Another approach:

```
for a = eye(N)
    a = a.';
    %'// do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use
`a(1,j)=1`
which will only change the jth element to 1. If you want to reassign 0 to other members of a, if it was changed before, you can then use
`a(1,1:j-1)=0
a(1,j+1:length(a))`
to set all non jth terms of a to 0.
If you provided us with clearer description of what you want to use a for, we may be able to help you better :)